# Mac Office 2008 Development- AppleScript vs. VBA

Tags: vba, macos, applescript, powerpoint

I'm looking for some advice from anyone who has experience writing addons for PowerPoint on both Windows and Mac machines.

We have a Windows Office 2007 addon (.NET) that we'd like to port to the Mac.

Thus, in PowerPoint 2008 for the Mac, we require the following functionality:

- Ribbon/Fluent extensibility
- Custom Task Panes
- Read/write custom document properties
- Save slides as images

  Read text and shape information from slides

  Get notification of the following PowerPoint application events; `SlideSelectionChanged`, `PresentationClose` and `AfterPresentationOpen`.

I am hoping someone with experience writing Office addons for Windows and Mac, can advise.

Comment: it's a good question. i haven't worked on powerpoint in mac or programming against it, but i'm really interested in what others have to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't solve your problem if you need to specifically do this in 2008, but Office 2011 is coming and it brings back VBA. Spending the effort to convert your stuff to AppleScript might be a lot of work for little return where you could wait for Office 2011 which brings the Ribbon to Mac Office as well as VBA...

http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9085678/Microsoft_will_bring_back_macros_to_Mac_Office_in_2011

Comment: even though this didn't answer my question, it solves the problem. Thanks!